# Kill Camera App Programmatically on Android

Tags: android, camera, device-admin

I am currently looking into creating a location aware security app whereby the camera is disabled if the phone moves into a designated location. I am now able to disable and enable the camera using the Device Administrator class and calling `setCameraDisabled` to disable the camera. However, the problem I am encountering now is that if the `setCameraDisable` method is called when the camera is running, the camera app doesn't close. The camera app would only be disabled on the next launch. As such I am wondering is there is a way for me to kill the camera process before calling the `setCameraDisabled` method. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```